# find_all doesn't find all tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

os:macOs Monterey 12.1

```
import json

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium.webdriver import support


url = "http://ysweb.yonsei.ac.kr:8888/curri120601/curri_pop_mileage_result01.jsp"

data = {
    "yshs_hyhg": "20212",  
    "yshs_domain": "H1",  
    "yshs_hakno": "NUR2021",  
    "yshs_bb": "01",  
    "yshs_sbb": "00",  
}

res = requests.post(url, data=data)  
res.raise_for_status()  


soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")


table_list = soup.find_all("table")


print(len(table_list))

print(table_list[1].text)
```

This is my code.
There are 4 table tags on the html script that i want to scrap but find_all("table") just finds the first table tags.
So, the result of `print(len(table_list))` is 1
and `print(table_list[1].text)` results in

```
"print(table_list[1].text)
IndexError: list index out of range"
```

How do i find all 4 table tags??

Comment: Lists in python are 0 based indexes. Try `print(table_list[0].text)`

Comment: i check your site, and found just one "table" tag on it. May be you mean something else?

Comment: I guess you cheked "http://ysweb.yonsei.ac.kr:8888/curri120601/curri_pop_mileage_result01.jsp"

Comment: I want to scrap the site that comes when I do requests.post(url, data=data)